# Properly mapping first names to emails?

Tags: python, regex, iterator

I am working on a research project and I have a list of about ~200 names and 6 email addresses. The requirement is to map every one of those emails to a single email address following this requirement:

"Names starting with A, B, C, D, E will map to email1. F, G, H, I, J will map to email2" and so on and so forth.

Now I'm trying to think of a way to map those names to the specific email in a fashion of "if *name* starts with *A-E* then *email1*, rather than iterating through all the names and checking for the starting letter of each name. Is there a way to accomplish this? I'm thinking RegEx might help, but not sure exactly how (possibly something along the lines of `^[a-eA-E]`?)

Comment: expected output?  expected input?

Comment: I've resolved the problem. I will iterate over all the names, do a `if re.match('^[a-eA-E]', name)` and assign the email based on that. 

Expected output, if I wasn't clear, would be a dictionary with "name" and "email" keys and their respective values, and expected input is a list of names.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `re` module has an undocumented [Scanner class](http://www.evanfosmark.com/2009/02/sexy-lexing-with-python/) which can be used to attach an arbitrary function call to regex patterns. When the `Scanner.scan` method is called, the supplied text is matched against each regex pattern, and the associated function is called when a match is found. The scan method ends when the remaining text matches none of the patterns.

```
import re

def make_email(i):
    def email(scanner, token):
        print('{t}: Send to email{i}'.format(t=token, i=i))
    return email

scanner = re.Scanner(
    [(pat, make_email(i))                                    # 2
     for i, pat in enumerate((r"^[a-e]\w+", r"^[f-j]\w+"))]  # 1
    + [(r"\s+", None)],
    flags=re.IGNORECASE|re.MULTILINE)

scanner.scan("""\
Albert
Barry
Carrie
David
Erin
Franklin
Geoff
Harold
Isadore
Jay""")
```

prints

```
Albert: Send to email0
Barry: Send to email0
Carrie: Send to email0
David: Send to email0
Erin: Send to email0
Franklin: Send to email1
Geoff: Send to email1
Harold: Send to email1
Isadore: Send to email1
Jay: Send to email1
```

---

1. You can add more regex patterns here.
2. The Scanner class is initialized with a list of 2-tuples. Each
   2-tuple consists of a regex pattern, and the associated callback
   function.

Comment: This is _exactly_ what I was looking for. Can't believe it's undocumented - looks like a contribution is in order on that end! Thanks a ton.

Comment: -1 I just think this is a pretty clumsy approach to the actual problem. It's interesting information, but there's just no need here for regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to know the first letter in each name, and map it to an email address. You don't need a regex for that.

```
def address(name):

    addresses = ['foo@bar.com', 'spam@eggs.org', ... ]

    i = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'.find(name[0].lower()) // 5
    return addresses[i]
```

Then you *want* to iterate over the names.

```
for name in names: print(name, address(name))
```

Comment: This presupposes that the email addresses are really that simple.  I'm guessing in reality they aren't. You could put them in an array and use `n(name)` as the index into that array but a dictionary would make more sense at this point.

Comment: The question is very clear about the mapping being between names that begin with a certain letter and email addresses, so you still don't want to be using `re` for that. Acknowledged, if the email addresses were more complex, you'd probably use a dict. I was just aiming to show that the accepted answer is overkill.

Comment: I updated the answer to show how to use a list as you suggested. The problem as defined just doesn't require anything more complex than that.

Answer (score 0):

The simple and straightforward solution is to create a simple dictionary with regexes as keys, and loop over those.

```
import re
mappings = { r'^[a-e]': "email0", r'^[f-j]': "email1" }
for name in names:
    for regex in mappings:
        if re.match(regex, name, flags=re.IGNORECASE):
            print "%s: send to %s" % (name, mappings[regex])
            break
    else:
        print "%s: no match" % name
```

If you do this on an industrial scale, you would probably want to precompile the regexes with `re.compile()` but for a quick and dirty solution, this gets the job done.

Comment: -1 I didn't want to downvote and not comment -- I've made my case against regexes elsewhere in the thread.

Comment: I mainly wrote this to point to a less esoteric solution than the accepted answer. For this simple case, agree that regex is probably overkill, but this should be simple to extend for a variety of other similar use cases where the mappings are not all that straightforward.